# Need help understanding why I get the logic circuit wrong

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

Could someone care to explain why the logic circuit for this boolean expression doesn't look like this?

[image]

[image]

When I select "build circuit," on Logisim, I get a different result:

[image]

Comment: A guess would be, 5 gates (optimized) is better than 6.

Comment: The lower circuit is the obvious literal translation of the boolean expression (ie. (q1+q0+b) AND a AND (/q0+/b)). How did you derive your version?

Comment: @rdtsc You could pretty trivially get it to four gates (De Morgan transformation of the bottom or gate) if that's what this was going for. I think it's actually just putting the plain product-of-sums form with however many inverters are required.  You can see that even the order of the inputs is the same as the order in which they appear in the formula.

Comment: Your circuit is obviously wrong- output is always 0 since a is anded with a’.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany what is obvious to you may not be obvious to everyone:)

Answer (score 0):

The equation given is an AND gate with three inputs: one of the input signals directly and two OR gates. It is easy to see that your expected logic circuit is incorrect because those gates do not match. I am not sure what reasoning led you to make *a(~q0+~b)* into two separate AND gates, but *a* should be a direct input to the final AND gate, and *~q0+~b* should be the other.
A good challenge for you would be to work the other way now: find the equation of your expected logic gate setup, and make the resulting truth table.
To check your work, here is what you would find:

> (q1 + q0 + a)(a AND ~q0)(a AND ~b).
>     __________
>       |0 0 0 0
>  |0 0 0 0
>       |0 0 0 0
>       |0 1 0 0

Comment: " I am not sure what reasoning led you to make a(~q0+~b) into two separate AND gates," I made the assumption that a~q0 + a~b, that is, two AND gates that merge into a OR gate(?)

Comment: Well you never merge those into an OR gate in your logic gate setup. If you had, then yes that would been equivalent, assuming you fix the NOT gate to be on the *b* input instead of the *a* input. However, by doing so you also made a lot more work for yourself, and then its easier to make simple mistakes (like leaving out an OR gate). It's important to keep logic gates simplified because it does not take much for it to get very complex.